# Changing format of debug output

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I change the format of ROS_INFO/ROS_DEBUG, etc so that it prints out the filename and line number that it was called from?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/102076/changing-format-of-debug-output/) by [vhwanger](https://answers.ros.org/users/3648/vhwanger/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2013-11-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
export ROSCONSOLE_FORMAT='[${severity}] [${time}] [${file}:${line}]: ${message}'
```

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2013-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vhwanger](https://answers.ros.org/users/3648/vhwanger/) on 2013-11-18**:
Thanks! Is there a way to not get the full path to the file?

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-11-18**:
mmm...  not to my knowledge, sorry; yeah... its too verbose. However, when you write ROS_XXX log macros, you can add a _NAMED suffix specifying who is writing the log messages; not but idea at all in big, complex nodes.